# Adding a variation to existing product with existing attributes

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

I'm trying to figure out the way how to add variation to existing product that is not originally variable product.

So I have a product Shirt and I get another one of those in stock in different color so my product importer needs to add a new variation to this existing product.

```
wp_set_object_terms ($product_id, 'black', 'pa_color', 1);

$attr_data = Array(
            'pa_color'=>Array(
                'name' => 'pa_color',
                'value' => '',
                'is_visible' => '1',
                'is_variation' => '1',
                'is_taxonomy' => '1'
            )
        );
update_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', $attr_data);
```

This adds a color to my product but destroys all my existing attributes on the product. Pulling the existing _product_attributes just gives me serialized attributes so just adding the new variation on top of everything isn't working.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the problem is that product_attribute is not a single variable and it seems that there is no merge in wp_set_object_terms

I solved my problem like this:

```
wp_set_object_terms ($product_id, 'black', 'pa_color', 1);

        $attr_data = Array(
            'pa_color'=>Array(
                'name' => 'pa_color',
                'value' => '',
                'is_visible' => '1',
                'is_variation' => '1',
                'is_taxonomy' => '1'
            )
        );

        $product = new WC_Product($product_id);

        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes', array_merge($product->get_attributes(), $attr_data) );
```

Answer (score -1):

I  having the same problems, and just resolved.

get term_id for product_type = variable

```
/**
    SELECT $wpdb->terms.term_id FROM $wpdb->terms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy 
    WHERE name = 'variable' 
    AND taxonomy = 'product_type'
    AND $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id
    LIMIT 1
**/

$variable_term_id  = 4;

wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $variable_term_id, 'product_type' , true); //for variable product
```

:)